# Why doesn't this happen to Hulk or Iron Man in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* Bruce and Iron Man

> snap for the first time

yet they don't visit the

> metaphysical realm like Thanos did where he meets Gamora.

Why is that so?

Comment: Maybe Thanos *wished* for the it? We're not even sure if it was actually Gamora.

Comment: My theory is that either they did, and we just didn't see it, or that they didn't because they themselves weren't the recipient of the Soul Stone via sacrifice (IE, only Clint would have had such a vision, of Natasha).

Comment: Is visiting the metaphysical realm a *rule* in-universe? To be honest, I didn't even think it's "real" or even related to the stones -  I thought that was just a small daydream Thanos had.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Out of universe, the directors planned to have a scene in the metaphysical realm with Tony and an older version of his [daughter Morgan](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2019/05/avengers-endgame-katherine-langford-role-details-why-cut):

> Apparently, Langford was going to play the older version of Tony’s daughter, Morgan (Lexi Rabe); her cameo would have occurred right after that climactic snap of Tony’s fingers. “There was an idea that we had that Tony was gonna go into the metaphysical way station that Thanos goes into when he snapped his fingers,” Joe Russo explained

The scene was shot but didn't seems to work as intended and was removed from the final cut. I don't know about any scene with Bruce Banner.

> "We showed it to a test audience, and it was really confusing for them." (...) Joe also clarified further: “The intention was that his future daughter. (...) And the idea felt resonant. But it was just too many ideas in an overly complicated movie.” “What we realized about it was we didn’t feel an emotional association with the adult version of his daughter,” Anthony Russo added. “It wasn’t ringing to us and resonating with us on an emotional level, which is why we moved away from it.”

In-universe, we don't know how the metaphysical realm is working. It seems that it is related to the Soul Stone because of the colours of the scene with Thanos and Gamora but we don't know whether it is an automatic consequence of the use of the Soul Stone (the stone wanting its holder to reflect about his/her actions?)

My guess is that, contrary to other stones like the Power and Time Stones that seem to be powerful passive tools, the Soul Stone is sentient, at least to some extent: it can understand the soul of its holder and his/her intentions. This solves some questions related to the stone:

1. Could someone trick the stone by making a subordinate sacrifice a person he loved on Vormir?
2. About the rules for the sacrifice on Vormir: Black Widow sacrificed herself on Vormir, so she should be the legitimate holder of the stone. Why could Hawkeye hold the stone? He was also on Vormir so it kind of makes sense. But why would Hulk or Iron Man be worthy of using the Soul Stone?

If this is correct, then it follows that the user of the Soul Stone is not automatically transported into the metaphysical realm. Thanos went there either because he wished it or because the stone felt he needed it. Clearly, talking to Gamora gives closure to his quest. Probably, Hulk and/or Iron Man didn't wish/need that.

Note that, it is not because we didn't see such a scene that it didn't happen. Maybe Tony visited the Metaphysical realm to talk with old Morgan. Maybe Hulk visited the Metaphysical Realm and met Black Widow there.

Edit: I see two problems with my theory:

1. why are the Avengers allowed to use the Soul Stone twice? After Hulk snap half of the Universe back into existence, what Black Widow sacrificed for has been realized, so the Soul Stone should have required another sacrifice. I guess this is solved by the fact that Tony knew he would die for sure, hence sacrificing himself to the Soul Stone (nothing really says that the sacrifice has to be made on Vormir).
2. The biggest problem: why would Thanos be able to use the Soul Stone in the finale battle of Endgame? He is not yet the Thanos that sacrificed Gamora, and Black Widow's sacrifice means nothing to him.

Comment: On Vormir the rules that the Red Skull present is that you must 'lose that which you love', so even though Black Widow sacrificed herself Hawkeye still lost what he loved and thus was given the stone. Also, the soul stone doesn't require a sacrifice every time it's used, only that it's needed to gain the power of the stone. Once the have it they can use it however they like like any stone. This same thing applies to Thanos in Endgame, he already has the stone, he doesn't have to be deemed worthy of it or anything.